# Questions asked during video game job interviews?

Tags: design, sound, game, job, interview

I've managed to get a skype interview for a position of Junior Sound Designer in a big game compagny. I'm french and my english oral skills are a bit rusty, so i'd like to train a bit before this interview (I wouldnt want to miss this opportunity because of my language skills).

So I was wondering if people who already went to this interview process would be ok to share their experience and what questions were asked to them.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Exciting!  Good Luck!